# How to extract named destinations with its page using only pdftk and grep?

Tags: grep, pdf, pdftk

I'm wondering if it's possible to extract named destinations of [this](http://sistemas.tce.ac.gov.br/diario/faces/paginas/publico/dec/visualizarDOE.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&dataDEC=25-05-2021) PDF using only pdftk and grep.I know it's possible to do the job with `pdfinfo -dests`. Its output is:

```
Page  Destination                 Name
   1 [ XYZ   74  581 null      ] "COMUNICAÇÕES PROCESSUAIS"
   8 [ XYZ   74  803 null      ] "COMUNICADO"
   8 [ XYZ   74  785 null      ] "DECISÕES PLENÁRIO/CÂMARAS"
  15 [ XYZ   74  803 null      ] "LICITAÇÕES E CONTRATOS"
  16 [ XYZ   74  803 null      ] "PAUTA"
```

Looking for /Names tag in pdftk output, I found:

```
/Names [(COMUNICADO) 7 0 R (COMUNICA��ES PROCESSUAIS) 4 0 R (DECIS�ES PLEN�RIO/C�MARAS) 9 0 R (LICITA��ES E CONTRATOS) 10 0 R (PAUTA) 12 0 R]
```

What is half the way of what I'm looking for. But, I don't know how to extract the named destinations along with its page number.

Comment: Not reliably, unless you use a heavy amount of scripting. But it seems you already know how to do what you want with pdfinfo, is there a reason you are looking for a different solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do that without installing another version of poppler in a different path,  e.g. "/usr/local/src"

Comment: That makes sense. If you really want to, you can search for the object corresponding for a reference (e.g. "7 0 R" is a pointer to an object that begins with "7 0 obj") and that should have information about the destination. But I would recommend against that; installing another copy of poppler will be much less painful.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, it's great to know that